# Google chrome <select> bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When I click an option from a select tag, other div gets the hover state.
This only is happening to me under Google Chrome in Windows 8, 7 and XP.
In Chrome for mac it's working good.
In Firefox, Safari and IE in Windows too... even in IE8!

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="hide" href="">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="hide">Menu 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="hide">Sub menu  1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="hide">Sub menu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 5</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a class="hide">Sub menu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sub item 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Sub menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub menu 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub menu 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="ComboLetra11" style="width:80px;">
                  <option selected="selected" value="__">Select 01</option>
                  <option value="01">ASD 01</option>
                  <option value="02">ASD 02</option>
                  <option value="03">ASD 03</option>
                  <option value="04">ASD 04</option>
                  <option value="05">ASD 05</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="ComboLetra11" style="width:120px;">
                    <option selected="selected" value="__">Select 02</option>
                    <option value="M3">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="AR">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="AA">Option 3</option>
                    <option value="AU">Option 4</option>
                    <option value="AV">Option 5</option>
                    <option value="G3">Option 6</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I made an example where you can see that if you click in the 2nd and 3rd option from the "select 02" tag, the :hover state for the "Menu 2" is activated.

http://codepen.io/jorgegirao/pen/tckwl?editors=110

Comment: I also face exact same problem

Comment: Nope, works fine for me in Chrome 44

Comment: What is your Chrome version ? coz, I'm on Windows8.1, and Chrome 44.0.2403.157 - and I don't see any such issue for your pen example ! everything seems to be perfectly working.

Comment: same for me. I don' t see anything strange happening

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I was able to create a workaround for this. 
On the menu's parent element, put the following:

`onmouseover="document.getElementById('ID OF UL').style.zIndex = '1';"` `onmouseout="document.getElementById('ID OF UL').style.zIndex = '-1';"`

Then on the the next element after that one, put the reverse:
`onmouseover="document.getElementById('ID OF UL').style.zIndex = '-1';"` `onmouseout="document.getElementById('ID OF UL').style.zIndex = '1';"`

Obviously, you might have to change it around a bit depending on the structure of the page you are using.  But basically the menu should have a z-index of -1 when you are not using it.  Don't forget you will need a position relative or absolute;

Not pretty, but I just spent 20 hours trying to solve this, and I can barely find anyone even complaining about it, let alone a cleaner solution.